# Excel application opened with Access VBA will not close in Task Manager

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I create an Excel.Application and after saving the workbook (wb) I attempt to terminate Excel with `.Quit` and `xl = nothing`. But there is an Excel Application in Task Manager.

```vb
Private Sub Befehl173_Click()
    SQL = "SELECT Projekt FROM Projekt WHERE ID = " & projektNummer & ";"
    Set result = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    tmp = result.Fields.Item(0).Value
    DoCmd.OpenQuery _
    "Abfrage4"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Abfrage4", acFormatXLSX, "P:\Datenbanken\Export\" & tmp & "_" & Date & ".xlsx"
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Abfrage4"
    
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    
    Dim myRange As Excel.Range
    Set xl = New Excel.Application
    strInputFile = "P:\Datenbanken\Export\" & tmp & "_" & Date & ".xlsx"
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(strInputFile)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Abfrage4")
    
    lastrow = wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("b" & lastrow + 1) = "Gesamt"
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("c" & lastrow + 1) = xl.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("c2:c" & lastrow))
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("d" & lastrow + 1) = xl.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("d2:d" & lastrow))
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("e" & lastrow + 1) = xl.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("e2:e" & lastrow))
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("f" & lastrow + 1) = xl.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("f2:f" & lastrow))
    
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("c" & lastrow + 1).Font.Bold = True
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("d" & lastrow + 1).Font.Bold = True
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("e" & lastrow + 1).Font.Bold = True
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("f" & lastrow + 1).Font.Bold = True
    
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("C:F").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("C1").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("D1").Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("E1").Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").Range("F1").Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    
    wb.Sheets("Abfrage4").UsedRange.Borders.Weight = 2
    
    wb.Save
    wb.Close (True)
    
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    xl.Quit
    
    Set xl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the objects in the reverse order:

```
wb.Save
wb.Close (True)
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
```

and why not use your ws worksheet object:

```
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Abfrage4")

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("b" & lastrow + 1) = "Gesamt"
```

Comment: changed the order but still the same problem. Excel is opened in Taskmanager.